# Not able to parse json node with json_decode() in php

Tags: php, json, parsing

here is the json string in the variable which i am trying to parse with json_decode() function. I am trying to retrieve a specific node information with it but its showing me the blank white page. want to try with the file_get_contents() also to get json string from outer file.
I have alreay seen the answer on the previous questions but that didn't helped me

```
<?php
//$json = file_get_contents('jsonfile.json');
$json = '[
{
    "selfie": {
        "post_author": "2",
        "post_date": "2014-12-02 13:00:00",
        "post_date_gmt": "2014-12-02 13:00:00",
        "post_content": "this is an example content",
        "image": "http://ssomesite.com/webservice/uploads/support.jpg",
        "post_title": "TestJSON"
    }
}
]';
$result = json_decode ($json);
echo $result->selfie->post_date;
//echo $result->selfie;
?>
```

Comment: Any errors in the PHP log?

Comment: @Barmar no actually i am on shared hosting can't have access to the log

Comment: Always remember to do a `print_r($json)` or `vardump($json)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $result[0]->selfie->post_date;
```

Comment: oh sorry @rut2 i was using wrong varibale put $data on behalf $result.

Comment: It has to be work I can see on my screen. can you tell me what error is firing ?

Comment: ohhh its ok bro :-) thats people call coding :D

Comment: now there is not error with it. its showing me the node value. But i want it to be work with the outer file also for that i am using file_get_contents('outerfile.json) with that its not working. can you help me with it too?

Comment: yeah sure, is there any error while decoding that ?

Comment: let me check, where can be the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66204/discussion-between-rut2-and-harish-kumar).

Answer (score 2):

Your object path is wrong. It should be

```
echo $result[0]->selfie->post_date;
```

...because the JSON begins with an array, of which your selfie definition is in the first element, hence `[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON format defines an array, containing a single object, with a single property called `selfie`, you need to access the data like so:

```
echo $result[0]->selfie->post_date;
```

If ever a JSON string cannot be parsed, the best thing to do is check what [`json_last_error`](http://www.php.net/json_last_error) and [`json_last_error_msg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) tell you abot what went wrong.

Comment: @HarishKumar: You're welcome. Would you mind awfully accepting one of the answers (the one that helped you the most), and/or up-voting any helpful answers, too?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing that parent array. You need to consider the array also:

```
<?php
$json = '[
{
    "selfie": {
        "post_author": "2",
        "post_date": "2014-12-02 13:00:00",
        "post_date_gmt": "2014-12-02 13:00:00",
        "post_content": "this is an example content",
        "image": "http://ssomesite.com/webservice/uploads/support.jpg",
        "post_title": "TestJSON"
    }
}
]';
$result = json_decode ($json);
print($result[0]->selfie->post_date);
?>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/C4Xa6Kod)

Comment: yeah thanks man for your effort @rut2 is already give me this answer. and its working fine. can you please also help me work this with outer file using file_get_contents()?

Comment: share you file contents.

Answer (score 0):

That's an array object. Instead of using `$result->selfie->post_date`. Use:

```
var_dump($result[0]->selfie->post_date);
```

Comment: Why do you need the var_dump? just the reference to the index 0 is needed as the other 3 answers show

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//$json = file_get_contents('jsonfile.json');
$json = '[
{
    "selfie": {
        "post_author": "2",
        "post_date": "2014-12-02 13:00:00",
        "post_date_gmt": "2014-12-02 13:00:00",
        "post_content": "this is an example content",
        "image": "http://ssomesite.com/webservice/uploads/support.jpg",
        "post_title": "TestJSON"
    }
}
]';
$result = json_decode ($json,true);
$rs = (array)$result;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($rs);
die;
?>

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [selfie] => Array
                (
                    [post_author] => 2
                    [post_date] => 2014-12-02 13:00:00
                    [post_date_gmt] => 2014-12-02 13:00:00
                    [post_content] => this is an example content
                    [image] => http://ssomesite.com/webservice/uploads/support.jpg
                    [post_title] => TestJSON
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

After researching a lot i found that the file_get_contents() is actually getting data from the file but due to its encoding its having some junk character before json like this ï»¿

so for this i changed the encoding to utf8 (BOM or without BOM) and its works fine now.

with the json string in the same file was already answered by @rut2 and other developes too. I appreciate their effort to solve my problem.